# how to splits number String android

Tags: android, split

I have some problem with splitting String , I'm able to split minute and seconds from the my custom time picker but after that I'm storing minute in string and show it. (for eg: minute = 33)

1. I want to show this both 33 in different EditText like in first edittext display 3 and second edit text will display another 3.
2. So, Can I store this it in String and display 33 ??
3. How can i splits this both 33 and display both in different edittext ?

I want Timer,which start and stop from the clicking button for that, I need custom time picker to take time (its requirement) and this time i have to put it in edittext to start timer , mytimer is like four column ( four edittext ) first two for minute and second two for seconds like minute 33 and seconds 45 then it store ,

```
 first EditText = 3
 second EditText = 3
 third EditText = 4
 fourth EditText = 5
```

I successfully got time from the my time picker in string 33:45 but how my problem is that how this 33 put in different edittext. and how 45 put in different edit text as 4 and 5.

Comment: If you want to split minutes into two edit text, as minutes is always of 2 digits, extract the first index and the second index separately. It would be nice if you could show what you have tried so far?

Comment: In what form you are getting the time ? 33:45 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following it working to me ,

```
    char first_digit=f_mins.charAt(0);
    char second_digit=f_mins.charAt(1);

    char third_digit=f_sec.charAt(0);
    char fourth_digit=f_sec.charAt(1);

    System.out.println(" minute splits = "+ first_digit + " : "+ second_digit);
    System.out.println(" minute splits = "+ third_digit + " : "+ fourth_digit);

    etTimertext1.setText(String.valueOf(first_digit));
    etTimertext2.setText(String.valueOf(second_digit));
    etTimertext3.setText(String.valueOf(third_digit));
    etTimertext4.setText(String.valueOf(fourth_digit));
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a String, convert it to char[] using

> char[] minArray = minString.toCharArray();

Then simply set the EditText

Comment: after that its need to convert in String ?>

Comment: Use the `String.vaueOf(char)`

Answer (score 1):

You just split that String minute into two string using index of that string

```
char first_digit=minute.charAt(0);
char second_digit=minute.charAt(1);
```

Then settext to your own edittext